# Can there be more than one EOL character in a DOS FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Does anyone know of a way to have more than one character be the "eol" character in a DOS batch script. I would like to use both ';' and '#' as characters to comment a line.

```
type t.txt
this is a line
#this is a commented line
;is this a commented line
last line

for /f "usebackq tokens=* eol=; eol=#" %f in (`type t.txt`) do (echo "%f")
"this is a line"
";is this a commented line"
"last line"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* eol=;#" %f in (`type t.txt`) do (echo "%f")
#" was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest the for loops an in the inner to define another eol:

```
for /f "usebackq eol=; delims=" %%f in (`type t.txt`) do (
    for /f "eol=# delims=" %%Z in ("%%~f")  do echo %%Z
)
```

But as a command line it could be a long expression...

What amazes me is that the `cmd.exe` does not complain about two eol definitions in the first example despite it taking only the first one. Another way is to filter the result with `FINDSTR`:

```
for /f  "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`type t.txt^| findstr /i /b /v "; #"`) do ( echo %%f )
```

or from command line:

```
for /f  "usebackq delims=" %f in (`type type.txt^| findstr /i /b /v "; #"`) do ( echo %f )
```

Also is possible with few IF conditions inside `FOR` loop but that will require delayed expansion and will be not so convenient for usage in command line.

Answer (score 2):

This command alone solve this problem as stated:

```
findstr /V /B "# ;" t.txt
```